# Custom paper size in crystalrepots viewer

Tags: c#, printing, crystal-reports

I have an application where I need the user to be able to print to a network printer through a print server.

The paper being used is `8 * 8` form feed paper. When I print to the printer from my development machine it works fine and I can print multiple documents with perfect alignment.

If I print from a test machine which has the paper size defined in the print server options with the same name as the one in the report the application prints to the alignment of letter size of 8 by 11.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Is your application server and printer attached to the server, is the same pc? or 2 different pc. Ideally you can not print into network printer from server (except you configure your network printer to your application server)

Comment: The printserver is a little box added to the printer to give it networking options instead of usb only. The test machine is bot the development machine. Also the application is installed onto the test machine and I also installed and ran it from the development machine with it working on the development machine only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-- I would comment instead of answer, but I don't have enough reputation -- 
Based on the description of the problem and your recent comment, it sounds like this may not be an issue with Crystal, as much as a problem with the client/user level printer configuration.

Are you able to print **anything** using the `8 * 8` using the test machine? It is just the Crystal Report that isn't aligned properly? 
One way to test whether crystal is operating correctly is to `export to pdf` from the test machine, or `print to pdf` - this will verify whether crystal reports is properly retaining the page configuration.